# How to get google logged in email id for Android Device having OREO (Android 8)

Tags: android, email, accountmanager, android-8.0-oreo

I want to get the email id from the Android phone having oreo. For below 8, I am able to get the email by using below code:

```
String emailId = "null";

// get the accounts info
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

// if the accounts are not null
if (accounts.length > 0 && accounts[0] != null) {
  emailId = accounts[0].name;
}
return emailId;
```

I am also getting the permission below: Runtime too. It is working in 7.0 too.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

Need to get the email id from the user account so to automatically display it on the screen while he wants to contact me through app!!

Comment: What makes you think that there will always be such an account? What makes you think that the user wants to use that account? Beyond that, you do not explain what the problem is when you try this code on Android 8.0+.

Comment: There will not be always an account associated, but I am talking about the case in which there is at least one account is present. I am able to get the email of that account below 8.0 but not for 8.0 above...